# Hibernate Validator Custom Constraint depends on base class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

Can I create a custom constraint with Hibernate Validator (w/i Spring boot), where the validation depends on sub class? Example:

```
public class Engine {
   @NotEmpty
   private String name;
   @NotNull
   private int power;
   @NotNull // HERE I ONLY NEED VALIDATE IF THIS CLASS ARE ONE PROP FROM Car Class
   private int color;

   ... getter and setter
}

Here I have 2 classes,

public class Car {
   @NotEmpty
   private String name;
   @Valid
   private Engine engine;
   ... getter and setter
}

public class Bike {
   @NotEmpty
   private String name;
   @Valid
   private Engine engine; // HERE I DONT NEED TO VALIDATE THE COLOR
   ... getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want using `@ConvertGroup`:

The group interfaces:

```
public interface BasicEngineChecks {
}

public interface ExtendedEngineChecks {
}
```

Updated example:

```
@GroupSequence({ BasicEngineChecks.class, ExtendedEngineChecks.class })
public class Engine {
   @NotEmpty(groups = BasicEngineChecks.class)
   private String name;

   @NotNull(groups = BasicEngineChecks.class)
   private int power;

   @NotNull(groups = ExtendedEngineChecks.class)
   private int color;

   // ...
}
```

There is nothing special about car. Cascaded validation will pass through the default group which gets translated to all constrains which are part of `BasicEngineChecks` as well as `ExtendedEngineChecks`

```
public class Car {
   @NotEmpty
   private String name;

   @Valid
   private Engine engine;

   // ...
}
```

For `Bike` we do a explicit conversion only evaluating `BasicEngineChecks`:

```
public class Bike {
   @NotEmpty
   private String name;

   @Valid
   @ConvertGroup(from = Default.class, to = BasicEngineChecks.class)
   private Engine engine; 

   // ...
}
```